# In-App Purchase: Invalid Product Identifier iOS 9 Swift 2

Tags: in-app-purchase, swift2, ios9

I keep getting this invalid product identifiers. Is my code fine? what could be the problem? Ive written the code to print out my in app purchases but it keeps going to this if statement:

```
if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count != 0 {
        print(response)
        print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)
    }
```

In my in-app purchase page on Itunes connect I have the exact ID for the product copied into xcode yet it still does not work.

My full code:

```
//global variables
var productsArray: Array<SKProduct!> = []
var productIdentifiers = Set<NSObject>()

func requestProductInfo() {
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        //let productIdentifiers = NSSet(array: productIDs)
        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: self.productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)

        productRequest.delegate = self
        productRequest.start()
    }
    else {
        print("Cannot perform In App Purchases.")
    }
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count != 0 {
        print("here")
        print(response)
        print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)
        print("here2")
    }

    if response.products.count != 0 {
        for product in response.products {
            productsArray.append(product)
            print(productsArray)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("There are no products.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, I guess you have problem with app bundle ID or Setting provisional profiles.

You must have to set **same BundleId and latest provisional profile(Certificates)** with enabled of "In-App purchase".

Comment: yes you can, I mean use your iTunes App bundle ID in which you enabled in-App purchases and also install once latest profiles which having in-app purchases enabled. These was help me.